# Silverlight: How to pass data from the request to the response using Webclient Asynchronous mode?

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to access VIP in the proxy_OpenReadCompleted method?

```
void method1() 
{ 
    String VIP = "test";
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    proxy.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(proxy_OpenReadCompleted);
    String urlStr = "someurl/lookup?q=" + keyEntityName + "&fme=1&edo=1&edi=1";
}

void proxy_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.  First is to pass the string as the second parameter in the `OpenReadAsync` call, this parameter becomes the value of the `UserState` property of the event args.

```
void method1() 
{ 
    String VIP = "test";
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    proxy.OpenReadCompleted += proxy_OpenReadCompleted;
    String urlStr = "someurl/lookup?q=" + keyEntityName + "&fme=1&edo=1&edi=1";
    proxy.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(urlStr, UriKind.Relative), VIP);
}    

void proxy_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{ 
   String VIP = (string)e.UserState;
   // Do stuff that uses VIP.
}
```

Another approach is to access the variable directly using a closure:-

```
void method1() 
{ 
    String VIP = "test";
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    proxy.OpenReadCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
         // Do stuff that uses VIP.
    }
    String urlStr = "someurl/lookup?q=" + keyEntityName + "&fme=1&edo=1&edi=1";
    proxy.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(urlStr, UriKind.Relative), VIP);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void method1() 
{ 
    String VIP = "test";
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    proxy.OpenReadCompleted += (s,e) => proxy_OpenReadCompleted(s,e,VIP);
    String urlStr = "someurl/lookup?q=" + keyEntityName + "&fme=1&edo=1&edi=1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if the async callback method writes into a databound variable, you are likely to get a cross-thread exception. You will need to use BeginInvoke() to get back to the UI thread. Here's an example using WCF services, but the principle is the same.

```
public void examsCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        EntityList<ExamEntity> examList = ((IExamService) result.AsyncState).EndGetAllExams(result);
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            foreach (ExamEntity exam in examList)
            {
                Exams.Add(exam);
            }
            ItemCount = Exams.Count;
            TotalItemCount = Exams.ItemCount;
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.Handle(ex);
    }
}
```